# sed to replace entire line with a string containing quotes

Tags: unix, awk, sed

My use case is, I have a json file which contains below:

```
{
"environment": {
"cf_org": "EMPTY",
"cf_shared_space": "EMPTY",
"cf_user_name": "EMPTY",
"cf_home_dir": "EMPTY",
"tenant_id": "EMPTY"
  }
}
```

I want to replace the line **"tenant_id": "EMPTY"** with **"tenant_id": ""**

I use the following code:

```
sed -i "/tenant_id/c\    \"tenant_id\" : "" $MYFILE.json
```

Am not able to get it working.

Note: The replacement string is **"tenant_id": ""** (everything highlighted in bold including the quotes)

Comment: Use a JSON-aware tool to work with JSON data.

Comment: The particular problem with the `sed` line above is only that the "" need to be quoted too, and then followed by a " which ends the argument.

Comment: Simpler to just use single quotes for sed's argument (that's good advice in general - use double-quotes only where you need parameter expansion to occur).  Like this: `sed -i '/"tenant_id": /s/"EMPTY"/""' "$MYFILE.json"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sed`, this feels simpler to me:

```
sed -i 's/"tenant_id": "EMPTY"/"tenant_id": ""/' $MYFILE.json
```

Even simpler, with no quoting needed:

```
sed -i "/tenant_id/s/EMPTY//" $MYFILE.json
```

Comment: Well the second solution worked for me and not the first one. Could you please provide a more elaborate description of the command? Thanks in advance

Comment: The first command was missing a " character, but I think it should work otherwise. The second uses /tenant_id/ to select all lines which match that word, and then uses the `s` command (substitute) to replace the word EMPTY with nothing.

Comment: ok understood....just being inquisitive here, what would the 1st command look like ? Because I had tried numerous approached with sed and i got the same error of Unexpected EOF(I faced the same with your 1st approach)

Comment: It works for me as it is written now. I copied and pasted it to my command line to check.

Comment: You might consider tighter matches - the second version here will match and modify `"cf_home_dir": "/usr/share/tenant_id/EMPTY_user/etc",` - as just one pathological case.

Answer (score 4):

Using jq:

```
$ jq '."environment"."tenant_id"=""' file
{
  "environment": {
    "cf_org": "EMPTY",
    "cf_shared_space": "EMPTY",
    "cf_user_name": "EMPTY",
    "cf_home_dir": "EMPTY",
    "tenant_id": ""
  }
}
```

Otherwise GNU awk and `split`:

```
$ awk '{
    split($0,a,": *",seps)    # consider comma separator with : for line endings
    if(a[1]~/\"tenant_id\"/)
        a[2]="\"\""
    print a[1] seps[1] a[2]
}' file
{
"environment": {
"cf_org": "EMPTY",
"cf_shared_space": "EMPTY",
"cf_user_name": "EMPTY",
"cf_home_dir": "EMPTY",
"tenant_id": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Not strictly necessary to quote the keys: `jq '.environment.tenant_id = ""' file` -- somewhat more readable. But upvote for using the correct tool.

Comment: True. I was strong in cut'n paste.

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '/"tenant_id": "EMPTY"/{$0=s1 "tenant_id" s1 ": " s1 s1} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/id": "EMPTY"/,"id\": \"\"")}1' file

output
{
"environment": {
"cf_org": "EMPTY",
"cf_shared_space": "EMPTY",
"cf_user_name": "EMPTY",
"cf_home_dir": "EMPTY",
"tenant_id": ""
  }
}
```